# Is there a place where I can automatically download news videos every day?

Tags: video, download-manager

How can I download news videos from the web automatically? I have a slow Internet connection which takes lots of time to buffer videos, so I was wondering if there was software that can automatically fetch/synchronize videos from websites to my HDD the same way each day. This would be from websites that legally provide news videos for download, kind of like how podcasts are distributed.

Comment: Should really close the question - but itunes can do this, just search for news organizations that offer rss feeds of their videos.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the media player/downloader [Miro](http://www.getmiro.com).  Particularly for their content aggregation at [Miro Guide](http://www.miroguide.com/).  It's another option if iTunes isn't what you want.